# how to display multiple components in list view

Tags: flutter

I am trying to build a list view in flutter which multiple components.  I am finding flutter listview to be limited on what you can add to each item. maybe there is a way to do what i want but im not sure how to do it.

here is my code

```
 ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: count,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
                return Column(
                    children: [
                      ListTile(
                        leading: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                          child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                        ),

                        title: Text('Social Security',                        
                          style: titleStyle,),

                         subtitle: Text('Weekly | Amex(Debit)',

                        trailing: Text('$45.00')


                        onTap: () {
                          debugPrint("ListTile Tapped");

                        },
                      )
                    ]
                );
              }
            );
```

[image]

in my code i am only able to display 3 components out of 6.
i am displaying an icon, a text next to it and subtext and another text on the right far side of the screen.  however, im missing subtext below $45.00 component and i dont know how to display the Pay On: date  on top of the icon and text.  please see image attached for an idea of what i want to display for each item in the list.  the red rectangle represent one item in the list. can someone help me modify my code to display a listview as the picture attached?

Comment: `ListView`'s items can be any kind of `Widget`(that's the beauty).
`ListTile` is only a easy way to implement simple lists using Material Guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may put fully-customize widget inside `title` parameter:

```dart
Widget complexListTile() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("Pay on: Wed, May 08 2019"),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
              child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("Social Security"),
                    Text("Weekly | Debit"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("\$45.00"),
                Text("Not Received"),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget complexListView() {
    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: 10,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
        return ListTile(
          title: complexListTile(),
          onTap: () {
            debugPrint("ListTile Tapped");
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: this is awesome. thanks Ejabu.  one more thing, is there any way to add a little bit more space between each item in the list ? if yes, please show me

Comment: SizedBox(height: 200) will do. Just put it inside Column, but put it as last element of children